# Could not find function "ksvm"

Tags: r, svm

I am just a beginner in using R. What I want is to use Support Vector Machine in R to predict/classify the status of bank. I also normalized my data already...

I divided my data into 2 parts: training and test part like this: (I have 7260 observations):

```
prediction1_train<-prediction1_n[1:5000, ]
prediction1_test<-prediction1_n[5001:7260, ]
prediction1_train_target<-prediction1[1:5000,7]
prediction1_test_target<-prediction1[5001:7260,7]
install.packages("e1071")
```

I've chosen

```
chooseCRANmirror()
```

but when I applied

```
model<-ksvm(STT~.,data=prediction1_train,kernel="linear",cost=10,scale=FALSE)
```

> Error: could not find function "ksvm"

So, pleased help me and tell me what should I do.

Comment: Rather than `install.packages("e1071")`, use `library(e1071)`.

Comment: thank you for your idea, I've tried but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

`ksvm()` is a part of kernlab library. You need to install kernlab package before executing your code.

```
install.packages("kernlab")
library(kernlab)
```

You can find more details [at this link](http://www.inside-r.org/node/63499).